# Create method in resource route not working ! Not showing content properly?

Tags: laravel, routes, resources

I'm using laravel 6.x version

index method in resource controller shows everything fine . But when i use create method it does not show content properly.

PostController defined like:

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.post.posts');
}
```

route defined as

```
Route::resource('admin/post', 'Admin\PostController');
```

When viewing in browser my content display with mismatch like ( over to over/bg color change, header or footer content posotion change etc etc)

But when i use index method and call the controller it shows everything fine

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.post.posts');
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us the view code ?

Comment: you can use php artisan route:list for which route will point to your method.

Comment: show code views for: index, create templates

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code

```
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
........
```

Comment: Just because you see the word `mismatch` doesn't mean it's a CSRF issue

Comment: @Saly3301 what's the problem?

Comment: Who knows ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I can't reproduce

Comment: I think, it because of CSRF issue. He might forget to put it in blade file.

Comment: No, it's not a form, he's just returning a view, the corresponding route is a GET|HEAD method

Comment: @Saly3301 Ohh I see!